# mod_rewrite public application files to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

In my web application, I have used mod_rewrite to keep all my PHP files organized under %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application

This .htaccess file redirects pretty much everything the way I want it to except directory index pages. For example:

"localhost" silently displays %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/index.php

"localhost/people/edit" silently displays %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/people/edit.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /application/$1 [L,QSA,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/api
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/css
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/images
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /application/$1 [L,QSA,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA,PT]
```

"localhost/people" redirects to "localhost/application/people/"
I assume this is something to do with the fact /people is a directory, and it's trying to pull /people/index.php. and show it as "localhost/people", but I'm not sure why after finding the correct file, it's publicly adding the "/application" part to the URL (which I want to remain hidden)

After several hours trying to figure this out, I've come to terms my .htaccess skills aren't capable of figuring this one out.

```
File structure for reference

public
↳ css
↳ application
  ↳ people
    ↳ index.php
    ↳ edit.php
  ↳ other
```

Comment: What are you using the `PT` flag for here?

Comment: tbh it was leftover in there from when I was trying to figure this out myself. It has no effect.